# How to check this i the same element JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table that I have to loop through the rows and skip the first row. I try to locate it and compare it but it didn't works.

```
var headerTr = $("GridView tr .header");
$("#GridView tr").each(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  if (headerTr === $this) {
    $this.show();
  } else {
    $this.hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: the tr has a class .header? because $("GridView tr .header"); will be $("GridView tr.header"); with no spaces. Or check if $(this).hasClass('header').

Comment: in this case: `headerTr[0] === this`

Comment: Also var headerTr = $("GridView tr .header"); should be var headerTr = $("#GridView tr .header");